# Simple C++ MIME parser

Tags: c++, mime, parsing

I want to digest a multipart response in C++ sent back from a PHP script. Anyone know of a very lightweight MIME parser which can do this for me?

Answer (score 17):

I know this may be too little, too late, but I had a similar need.  I wanted a mime parser that just did the encoding and decoding of the MIME.  For the sake of completeness and for Google-ability I thought I should put my findings here.  Keep in mind that I was not interested in send and receiving mail, just encoding and decode MIME.  Here are the libraries I researched for C++ MIME:

[http://www.vmime.org/](http://www.vmime.org) - Looks like too much. Contains pop, SMTP, tls, IMAP, could remove this.  Posix and windows.

http://codesink.org/mimetic_mime_library.html - looks promising.  Very nice api for reading in and creating messages. Went with this one. Not too heavy.  Had to “fix” 2 things. First for multipart the code was just check for the string “multipart” and did not recognize “multipart/mixed” and did not write out the parts. Secondly, I had to hack the mimeentity write code.  It was just writing out the std::deque Field and since these are strings it seem to be doing so alphabetically.  This is problem because the MIME-version has to be the first field written out. So I fixed this. I also had to add support for Content-Length.

http://www.mozilla.org/mailnews/arch/libmime-description.html - Hard time finding this.  Had to download the whole package. mailnews\mime\src

http://www.example-code.com/vcpp/smime.asp - Didn’t consider because it had no source code and was windows specific.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html - Couldn’t find this C implementation.

I chose Mimetic for my needs although I had to add a few things to it.  None of the parsers I found handled the optional fields (Content-Length, etc..) very well.  I also needed it to support multiple platforms (Windows, Linux, etc..)

Comment: http://www.scalingweb.com/mime_parser.php appears to have changed - now leads to a site selling weighing equipment.

Answer (score 8):

Not to toot my own horn here, but [GMime](http://spruce.sourceforge.net/gmime) is a very complete MIME parser written in C which can handle the Content-Length header. It also handles DOS and UNIX line-endings with ease, handles broken header charset encodings, doesn't require you to read the entire message into RAM, supports PGP/MIME, etc. It also has a very comprehensive set of unit tests that I use to prevent any regressions.

People have been building it on Windows for quite a while now (under cygwin and/or mingw32 afaik), but the past week or so I've been spending time making Windows a first-class priority by setting up Visual C++ Project/Solution files and making sure everything builds.

Figured I'd post even though you've already found a MIME parser just so other people who may have a similar question might see another option if the aforementioned solutions don't suit their needs.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using the [mime code](https://github.com/cpp-netlib/cpp-netlib/blob/master/mime/example/basic_parsing.cpp) from cpp-netlib with sucess so far. It is a [bit picky](https://github.com/cpp-netlib/cpp-netlib/issues/332) about syntax but works great.

Answer (score 0):

Better cut what you need with regex from mime multipart data faster. And don't need learn new libs. There is simple php parser https://github.com/breakermind/PhpMimeParser/blob/master/PhpMimeParser_class.php but with regex you can write it in c++ very simple. Only 357 lines.