# Is there a lightweight multipart/form-data parser in C or C++?

Tags: c++, c, parsing, multipartform-data, multipart

I'm looking at integrating multipart form-data parsing in a web server module so that I can relieve backend web applications (often written in dynamic languages) from parsing the multipart data themselves. The multipart grammar (RFC 2046) looks non-trivial and if I implement it by hand a lot of things can go wrong. Is there already a good, lightweight multipart/form-data parser written in C or C++? I'm looking for one with *no* external dependencies other than the C or C++ standard library. I don't need email attachment handling or buffered I/O classes or a portability runtime or whatever, just multipart/form-data parsing.

Things that I've considered:

- GMime - depends on glib, so no go.
- libapreq - too large, depends on APR, badly documented, no unit tests.

I've also looked at writing a parser with Ragel, but I can't figure out how to do it because the grammar is not static: the boundary can change arbitrarily.

Comment: "GMime - depends on glib, so no go." - care to explain why?

Comment: Have you read this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218089/simple-c-mime-parser ?

Comment: @John: Every new dependency adds installation hassle for my users, and I want to avoid that to a minimum. Many servers do not have glib installed. Also every new dependency increases resource usage. There aren't many server apps that use glib, so if I depend on glib I'll pull it all of its memory consumption just to parse some mime data.

Comment: Could you use GMime and link statically to avoid installation hassle?  I'm not 100% sure, but I suspect you could, and that the memory footprint probably wouldn't be an issue on most servers.

Comment: Just an FYI, but overhead from glib is tiny. Also, every Linux distro ships with glib by default and many include gmime by default as well.

Answer (score 10):

I know this question is a couple of years old now, but I needed the same and ended up using this:

https://github.com/iafonov/multipart-parser-c

Comment: Definitely check the issues though! E.g. the boundary term must be prefixed with "--" already, or else it won't work.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there one. No secret it is my own. Feel free to use it. The link is: [MPFDParser](http://grigory.info/MPFDParser). It has no dependencies at all.

Answer (score 1):

[mimetic](http://codesink.org/mimetic_mime_library.html) claims to support it. I think GNU [cgicc](http://www.gnu.org/software/cgicc/) may also support it.

Answer (score 1):

cgicc supports it... But is written quite badly and relays on entry buffer in memory.

Answer (score -6):

this may not answer your question directly, but did you consider hiphop for php from facebook?

it converts your php code to c++ then compiles with g++.

might save you time in writing something on your own.