# how to parse HTTP POST(file upload) stream?

Tags: c++, c, http, actionscript, post

I am using actionscript engine to upload a file, the engine will select the file and send the file over network thru HTTP POST command, the document says the POST message is like:

```
POST /handler.cfm HTTP/1.1
  Accept: text/*
  Content-Type: multipart/form-data; 
  boundary=----------Ij5ae0ae0KM7GI3KM7ei4cH2ei4gL6 
  User-Agent: Shockwave Flash 
  Host: www.example.com 
  Content-Length: 421 
  Connection: Keep-Alive 
  Cache-Control: no-cache

  ------------Ij5GI3GI3ei4GI3ei4KM7GI3KM7KM7
  Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Filename"

  MyFile.jpg
  ------------Ij5GI3GI3ei4GI3ei4KM7GI3KM7KM7
  Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo"; filename="MyFile.jpg"
  Content-Type: application/octet-stream

  FileDataHere
  ------------Ij5GI3GI3ei4GI3ei4KM7GI3KM7KM7
  Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Upload"

  Submit Query

  ------------Ij5GI3GI3ei4GI3ei4KM7GI3KM7KM7--
```

In server side I have a C++ program listens on port 80 and parse the POST message. I only want the file name and file data. How to decode the file data using c++, is it base64 encoded and is there a library can do it for me? I want to decode the binary, and write it to the file, thanks!

Comment: If you don't give a name to the submit button on the HTML, it won't get POSTed to the server (the "Upload" section) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no encoding. The body of each subpart of the multipart message is included as verbatim bytes. Consequently you have to be careful to choose a `boundary` string that doesn't occur anywhere in the file data.

To parse a multipart/form-data form submission you will enough of a MIME parser to parse the headers, pick out parameters you want like `boundary` and `name`, and split the received message by the boundary string. This is not completely trivial, so you may want to [consider existing libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218089/simple-c-mime-parser).

(Unfortunately, what browsers actually do in HTTP differs a bit from the standard MIME rules outlined in [RFC 1341](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html). In particular, field name and filename parameters tend to include non-ASCII characters and unescaped quotes. But if you are generating the POST yourself hopefully you can steer clear of these areas of contention.)

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of a "Content_Transfer_Encoding" header, it is assumed data is encoded in "7bit" ([RFC 1521](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1521.txt); [RFC 1867](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1867.txt); [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt)).

I don't know if tere's a `C` library to parse / decode HTTP POSTs. I'm pretty sure there are though :)

Comment: Oh, dude I really came here to see not C++, but particularly C lib for parsing boundary data and I'm also pretty sure there are some.

Answer (score 1):

You can upload unlimited size of `data/file`. Try this solution

```
const char* ctype = "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryfm9qwXVLSbFKKR88";
size_t content_length = 1459606;
http_payload* hp = new http_payload(ctype, content_length);
if (hp->is_multipart()) {
    int ret = hp->read_all("C:\\temp\\");
    if (ret < 0) {
        std::cout << hp->get_last_error() << std::endl;
        hp->clear();
    }
    else {
        std::string dir_str("C:\\upload_dir\\");
        ret = hp->read_files([&dir_str](http_posted_file* file) {
            std::string path(dir_str.c_str());
            path.append(file->get_file_name());
            file->save_as(path.c_str());
            file->clear(); path.clear();
            std::string().swap(path);
        });
        hp->clear();
        std::cout << "Total file uploaded :" << ret << std::endl;
    }
}
else {
    int ret = hp->read_all();
    if (ret < 0) {
        std::cout << hp->get_last_error() << std::endl;
        hp->clear();
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Posted data :" << hp->get_body() << std::endl;
        hp->clear();

    }
}
```

https://github.com/safeonlineworld/web_jsx/blob/0d08773c95f4ae8a9799dbd29e0a4cd84413d108/src/web_jsx/core/http_payload.cpp#L402